# Separate RouterOutlet for descendant paths

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to come up with a setup for my Angular application which will have two router outlets for views. Specifically:

**Main outlet:**
This outlet will encapsulate the application and will be used by paths like `/login`, `/password-reset`, and `/app`

**Secondary (content) outlet:**
This outlet will be within main root component (with path `/app`). The idea is that this root component will have other elements like **header**, **sidebar**, and **footer**, which don't have to be re-rendered, and will also have the secondary outlet for inner routes (e.g. `/app/dashboard`, `/app/users`) etc.

I made an illustrated example to visualize the problem:

[image]

So far, I have only managed to make the main outlet and one nested route. However, the problem is that when going deeper (e.g. `/app/users/create`), every level needs one separate `<router-outlet>` component. That is not good - my goal is to create a setup which will require only two outlets but will maintain the structure in routing as it is - keeping nested routes under `children` for future user in breadcrumbs etc.

Code sample on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-outlets

I hope I explained the issue good enough and thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I needed by using respective NgModules for each route that has any descendants. Eventually, I will switch to lazyloading completely and each route will have it's own NgModule with routes.

For those of you also struggling, feel free to fork the StackBlitz I tested it on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-outlets